# R "Could not find function <-<-" but I did not use that function

Tags: r, function, statistics, fstat

What I entered in the console (alp, DF1, DF2 are defined):

```
    LT <- left.tail=FALSE
    q <- qf(alp, DF1, DF2, LT)
    q
```

What I got:

```
     LT <- left.tail=FALSE
     Error in LT <- left.tail = FALSE : could not find function "<-<-"
     > q <- qf(alp, DF1, DF2, LT)
     > q
     [1] 0.4490486
```

The answer I am looking for is 2.22, which I get when the Lower Tail is defined as false.

Why is it telling me that "<-<-" is not avaible, I did not write this function?
And is there a way to store a TRUE/ FALSE value for lower.tail?

For further explanation, I am trying to write a code where I simply have to enter the values on the top and get the answer out of it:

```
data.entry(1)


a1 <- mean(var2)
v1 <- var(var2)
SD1 <- sd(var2)
n1 <- max(n)
a2 <- mean(var3)
v2 <- var(var3)
SD2 <- sd(var3)
n2 <- max(n)

int <- 1-0.9 #given interval
LT <- FALSE #Right Tailed- H1: >/ =/=
TT <- 0 #Two Tailes- H1: = / =/=

alp.O <- 0.1 #Given Alpha 
alp <- alp.O/(1+TT)
DF1 <- n1 - 1
DF2 <- n2 -1
q <- qf(alp, DF1, DF2, left.tail=LT) #ALP, DF1, DF2
f <- q-2*q*RT #t-Critical Value - Rejection Level
F <-  v1/v2 #Parameter of Interest1 / Parameter of Interest2
  
print(F==f)

print(F>f)

print(F<f)
```

It's not done yet and there are some residuals from older code, please ignore them.

Comment: Maybe you want `LT <- left.tail==FALSE`, which is `LT <- !left.tail` or use `LT <- left.tail <- FALSE` if it is what you want

Comment: You need  to do `LT = FALSE` and use it within the `qf` function. you do not need the `left.tail`

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a parser oddity in R.  The expression

```
 LT <- left.tail=FALSE
```

is parsed as

```
 (LT <- left.tail) = FALSE
```

which is the same as

```
 `<-`(LT, left.tail) = FALSE
```

which is the same as

```
 `<-<-`(LT, left.tail, FALSE)
```

which is where your error message came from.

I call this an oddity, because I would have expected it to be parsed the same as

```
LT <- left.tail <- FALSE
```

which assigns `FALSE` to `left.tail` and then to `LT`.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can assign using 2 different operators: `<-` and `=`.

That is, if you want to assign the value of 3 to the variable `x`, you can write either `x<-3` or `x=3`.

When you write: `LT <- left.tail=FALSE`, instead of *testing* whether `left.tail` is FALSE (which you'd do with the comparison operator `==`) you're setting up a double assignment – that is, assigning the value `FALSE` to `left.tail` *and* `LT`. You can actually do that if you use the same operator: `x=y=4` or `k<-d<-5` both work as expected. If you mix these operators, though, you get an error.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on behind the scenes to generate the function `<-<-`, but I do know it's a result of R trying to deal with combining the 2 different assignment operators in a single expression. If you do want to do the double assignment, just use the same operator:

```
LT <- left.tail <- FALSE
```

In your case, I don't think you want to do a double assignment. Likely, you want to test if `left.tail` is FALSE, and store that result in `LT`. You can do that in a few ways:

```
# Tests for only FALSE values
LT <- left.tail==FALSE
LT <- isFALSE(left.tail)

# Tests for "falsy" values like 0
LT <- !left.tail
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `falsy`? if `left.tail` is already `FALSE` then just `LT <- !left.tail` Note that `0` is indeed FALSE. ie check `0 == FALSE` which is done through implicit coercion. OP wants to assign and not compare. read through the question please

Comment: @Onyambu "Falsy" means values that evaluate to false but are not themselves false. `isFALSE(left.tail) ` only returns TRUE if `left.tail` is actually the logical value FALSE, wheras `!left.tail` will return TRUE for other values like 0. The choice depends on the specific needs of their program. And from their question, it's certainly not clear where the typo is: do they want to assign to both, or compare

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is

```
qf(p = alp, df1 = DF1, df2 = DF2, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Note that `qf(alp, DF1, DF2, FALSE)` passes `FALSE` to the fourth argument of `qf()`, which is `ncp` and not `lower.tail`.